# Android - Rotate image inside the button

Tags: android, button, android-animation

I want to rotate the image inside the button on click of the button. I tried with just ImageView and it works but for accessibility purpose I need to use Button instead of ImageView.

Before click : [image]

Here the down arrow is button background.

After Click : [image]

Click of button displays extra data and background arrow is rotated. How can I animate and rotate button background on click?

Layout code for reference :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cases_actions_row"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/case_action_item_1"
                    style="@style/card_action_button"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/case_action_item_2"
                    style="@style/card_action_button"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cases_expand_button"
                    style="@style/card_action_button"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `I tried with just ImageView and it works but for accessibility purpose I need to use Button instead of ImageView.` ... or use an ImageButton

Comment: Thanks Frank. I will go through the docs. Can I add animation while changing the image there?

Comment: `ImageButton` inherits from `ImageView`. But looks like a `Button`. So, if it works on an `ImageView` (you said so), it will work on an `ImageButton` too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest method would be to rotate the entire button (and as Frank N. Stein suggested in the comments, an `ImageButton` is probably best suited, although there's nothing to stop you from using a different widget).

There are several ways to rotate the button, but a `ViewPropertyAnimator` is again likely the most straightforward:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        float deg = button.getRotation() + 180F;
        button.animate().rotation(deg).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    }
});
```

**Edit:** By the way, if you want the arrow to reverse its original animation, you could instead try:

```
float deg = (button.getRotation() == 180F) ? 0F : 180F;
```

instead of `float deg = button.getRotation() + 180F;`

Comment: rotating the whole button would also rotate the button background if it has one

Comment: Yes, but that isn't an issue in the questioner's case

Answer (score 2):

You can set bitmap as background in button.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.postRotate(90);

Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg,width,height,true);

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

First take bitmap from any source and then rotate it and then set it as background in button.

```
BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap);
button.setBackground(bdrawable);
```