# How Do You Rotate An Icon On An ImageButton Without Rotating The Actual Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to rotate the icon inside an ImageButton an arbitrary amount *without* rotating the actual button itself?  In other words, can I put the icon at, say, a 45 degree angle while keeping the button in its original orientation?

Comment: In particular, in the duplicate, you would use [the `Matrix` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915261/115145), but apply it as the image of the `ImageButton`, not the background.

Comment: You could just use a regular button then place an image on top of the button. Could be tricky getting the press effect on both the button and the image.